# Brace match highlighting doesn't work in VS2010 for me

Tags: visual-studio-2010

The brace matching rectangles appear, but not the highlighting. I thought it might have something to do with the emacs keybinding, but it still doesn't work with the default keybinding. If it makes any difference, it's a .cpp/h files that are giving me problems (haven't tried other languages). I've waded through the various options and can't find anything that would turn off one form of matching without turning off the other.

Comment: [Maybe related to this?](http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/534997/brace-matching-highlight-doesnt-work)

Comment: @Steve - if you will post your comment as an answer, I can accept it as the correct answer. Thanks.

Comment: I've added it as an answer now. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that it is related to [this](http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/534997/brace-matching-highlight-doesnt-work) known issue.

Each language is free to use any setting it chooses from the visual styles, and there are known inconsistencies between languages and the settings that are used.